# Combining strings by different type in SQL PSQL or SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, string-aggregation

How to combine strings by different type in Mysql, PostgreSQL or SQL Server, below data `type = 1` is province and `type = 2` is city, I would like to combine them to a column,

```
name         code       type
Sichuan     610000       1    
Chengdu     610000       2
Hubei       430000       1
Wuhan       430000       2
```

and my expected output is below:

```
name              code
SichuanChengdu    610000
HubeiWuhan        430000
```

Comment: Scalar: MySQL - `CONCAT()` function, PostgreSQL - `||` operator, SQL Server - `+` operator.

Comment: Aggregate: MySQL - `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, PostgreSQL & SQL Server - `string_agg()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres you can use:

```
select string_agg(name, '' order by type) code
from the_table
group by code;
```